# Is $2n$ the smallest number of halfspaces to determine a segment in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-programming, polyhedra

I proved that a segment in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a polyhedron, and it is determined by $2n$ halfspaces. My question follows:

> Is $2n$ the smallest number of halfspaces to determine a segment in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

I assumed the contradiction but still got nothing. I think it may be related to some properties of adjacent extreme points.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: In $n-1$ dimension, you can use $n$ half spaces to determine a point. eg. $x_1 \ge 0, x_2 \ge 0, \cdots x_{n-1} \ge 0$  and $x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_{n-1} \le 0$ uniquely determine the origin. This means in $n$ dimension, $n$ half spaces is enough to determine a line. To specify a segment, you just need $2$ more to specify the end points. So in general, $n+2$ half spaces is enough to determine a segment in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the line segment in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with endpoints $(0,0,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$.  It is defined by these five halfspaces:
$$x+y\leq0,y\geq0,y-x\leq0,z\geq0,z\leq1$$